# Best practice for handling exceptions for both REST and Browser requests?

Tags: rest, grails, exception, grails-2.0, grails-controller

What is the best practice for handling exceptions in one Grails application(2.4.5) where there are REST requests and regular browser requests?

I am sharing the same ExceptionController between RESTful API calls and regular web requests.

UrlMapping.groovy
`"500"(controller: "exception", action: "handle")`

For regular web requests, this was calling 
    `render(view: 'show', model: model)`

Later a RESTful API was introduced. Since the exceptions will still route to the ExceptionController, I changed to
    `respond(view: 'show', model: model)`
This did not seem to work so I updated to

```
withFormat{
            html {render(view: 'show', model: model)}
            json {render model as JSON}
        }
```

That seems to work, but I'm not convinced it's the best solution.

Comment: Handling the response format in your error controller seems OK to me. Why you think this is not good?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same solution as i implemented yesterday, the only slight change was to specify `'*'` instead of `json`

```
withFormat{
  html {render(view: 'show', model: model)}
  '*' {render model as JSON}
}
```

In my case i also removed in `Config.groovy` the list of user agents whose `accept` header is ignored, but this is only relevant if you're using this header for content negotiation.